# How to remove the Powered by Odoo #1 Open Source eCommerce footer from front end of Odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I tried the Odoo8 trick it does not work .... There is no Powered by in

```
addons => web => views => webclient_templates.xml
```

and there is no `Footer Copyright` in user interface `views`.

Where can i find this line and possible remove it..

[image]

How to remove it permanently removing it from `User Interface => Views => Footer Copyright` removes it temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

1. Active developer mode.(Login as admin select About on the user menu the click Activate Developer mode)
2. Enable technical features.
3. Go to `Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views`.
4. In the search box, next to "(filter icon) Active", type `secondary`, and hit enter to search.
5. Choose `web.menu_secondary`.Click to open it.
   Now find this tag and put it comment like.

   ```
   <div class="oe_footer">
      Powered by 
      <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank">
        <span>Odoo</span>
      </a>
   </div>
   ```

Hope this will solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings -> User Interface -> Views

Select Login Layout

You will see the reference there.

The file is located

addons/web/view/webclient_templates.xml